# Azure App Service showing "This page isn't working right now http 400" but the request is "200 OK" in the logs

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, http-status-code-400, azureportal

I have an Azure Web App Service where I'm running my .NET 6 application. This application requires a server, which is running as Azure Container App (everything works fine in the server part).
When I run my web app service, I log in and afterwards see the following:
[image]

However on the server side I can see my request which returned 200 OK. There are no errors in the logs at all.

Another thing that I noticed, I went to KUDU to see the web app logs, and in the "Detailed Errors" I found the error that I get:
[image]

I also tried turning custom errors off in the web.config to see if I could get a more detailed error. But only got this:
[image]

There're absolutely no errors in the server.

I don't think that's helpful but I thought I should mention that.
Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure app service some requests returns 400 Bad Request. The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71322160/azure-app-service-some-requests-returns-400-bad-request-the-request-could-not-b)

Comment: [Diagnostics in Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-6.0#diagnosticsource) and [Connection logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#connection-logging-1)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT thanks for your comment. I did try that, there are some weird errors that I'm getting there so trying to figure them out now...

Answer (score 1):

As in the error page, the reason was not mentioned, this is perfectly the error due to the certificate on the domain which the web app service is running. This could be because of using the not proper format and syntax of the web app domain and that creates this issue.

**Missing the error number in logs:**

The **200:ok** is used to indicate that the request is successfully made, processed and executed and there is not error in the request and response.

As the data is not visible on the page and showing **400 error** even though it is **200:ok** from server side, this is purely the certificate error of the domain, regarding the data transmission and permissions.

**200:OK is not an error in logs**. It is a status code. Status code will be visible in the logs, as there is not error in the operation happened, it Will not show anything error in log as **status** is **OK**. The certificate is the reason behind the error. Need to check the domain and its certificate.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are probably right. I'll try to sort out the certificate stuff and see if it works