# Failed API call with JSON payload to ASP.NET API on Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm having an interesting problem. I make an API call to my ASP.NET API hosted on Azure App Service and the call fails with `400 Bad Request`. When I run the same API app locally and make the same call using identical data, it works fine.

The only thing I can see that could be a problem is the size of the string in one of the properties. The payload sends two long strings I get from AppStore: a purchase token and receipt data. Both are generated by Apple after an in-app subscription.

The receipt data is particularly long: 42,932 characters to be exact. The purchase token is long too but it's "only" 5,204 characters.

My JSON object which gets parsed into a class looks like this:

```
{
   "appId": 6,
   "productId": "monthly_subscription",
   "providerId": 2,
   "purchaseToken": "ewoJInNpZ...", // 5,204 character long string
   "receiptData": "MIJ9wQY..." // 42,932 character long string
}
```

And my API parses the JSON data into this class:

```
public class PurchaseVerificationRequest
{
   public int AppId { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string ProductId { get; set; }

   public int ProviderId { get; set; }

   public string PurchaseToken { get; set; }

   public string ReceiptData { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea what could be the issue here? As far as I know, JSON doesn't impose a limit for string sizes. I came across a possible setting `MaxJsonLength` but this is neither set in my app nor on Azure portal. Is there a general setting somewhere on Azure that sets a limit to string size in JSON objects?

P.S. My API app runs on the latest version of ASP.NET Core targeting .NET 8.0.101 and is hosted by Azure App Service using a Linux machine with a paid plan.

UPDATE:

This is still a mystery but we can rule out `MaxRequestBodySize` because I sent a POST request without any values for `purchaseToken` and `receiptData` properties and I'm still getting a `400 BadRequest` error even though it works perfectly fine locally.

UPDATE FINAL:

I've figured out the root cause of the issue though still investigating why it works locally and not on Azure.

Our API backend makes a REST call to Apple AppStore Connect API to verify the purchase. Turns out the `400 BadRequest` is not generated by our API but Apple's. It just bubbles up to our API's endpoint and it returns the `400 BadRequest` it received from AppStore Connect API.

The error messages were not descriptive enough so I had to remove logic in chunks to be able to pinpoint the issue.

I hope this helps someone else with a similar problem.

One of the key learning points from this experience is that the default `MaxRequestBodySize` on Azure is 128Kb which is actually quite a lot if you're sending HTTP requests with JSON payloads.

Comment: Any logging happening with the API -- for additional information / details?

Comment: Log stream doesn't show anything and I just activated App Insights a few minutes ago so waiting for some data.

Comment: In cases like these, I typically grab the raw request body (as a string), write it to a text file (before doing anything further) and then examine it for structure, invalid characters, etc.   Once you have the request captured, you can also "feed" the data into your local environment and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I'll do that. However, everything working perfectly locally and failing on Azure is interesting. BTW, I make the requests from a .http file so I know they're clean requests. The only thing I haven't inspected character by character is the receipt data because it's very long. I did do a visual check though and it looks legit.

Comment: Also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71322160/azure-app-service-some-requests-returns-400-bad-request-the-request-could-not-b   Of interest is the mention of " The 400 errors disappears when we use the azure internal-urls. (*.azurewebsites.net instead of *.ourdomain.net)" -- perhaps another thing to check?

Comment: @bdcoder Thanks for trying to help. I figured out the root cause of the issue. The `400 BadRequest` is not generated by our API but Apple AppStore Connect API. Unfortunately, the error messages were not clear so I had to do some digging. I provided more info in the UPDATE FINAL section of original post. Thanks again!

Comment: Please post your update as a self-answer to this question, instead of editing it into the question's body.

Comment: @IanKemp I will but first I want to understand why a call to AppStore Connect API works locally but not on Azure App Service.

Answer (score 0):

as a Given the details of your issue,
it seems like the problem is related to the HTTP request size limit set by the server,
rather than an issue with JSON string length limits per se. ASP.NET Core apps have configurable limits for request sizes,
and Azure App Services also have their own set of limits and configurations that might affect this.

so we have 2 options

first Configure ASP.NET Core Kestrel Server Limits: The ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server has settings to control the maximum request body size. For your scenario, adjusting the MaxRequestBodySize property of Kestrel server options could help. This can be done in the Program.cs or Startup.cs file of your ASP.NET Core application as in below sample code configure CreateHostBuilder  method by setting serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize to 52428800

second Adjust the Request Limits in the Azure App Service Configuration: Azure App Service has its own request size limits that might need to be adjusted. While there's no direct Azure portal setting for JSON body size, the request size limit can impact the transmission of large JSON payloads.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                {
                    // Set the maximum request body size to 50 MB
                    serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800;
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Comment: First, thank you for your response. I read it and made sense but a couple of points: as I understand it from the docs, the default size of `MaxRequestBodySize` on Azure App Service is 128K which should be plenty in my case. Total character count, including all the other properties in my JSON object is less than 50,000 characters. Nevertheless, I did set Kestrel `MaxRequestBodySize` so a much higher number but that didn't help either. Again, I do appreciate your help but so far this is still a mystery!

Comment: Also, see my update. Even if I don’t send those long strings, I’m still getting bad request error. Strangest thing!